# How to copy outlook mail tables to excel using vba based on a specific sender and specific date

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Here is the code :
Another problem is if that specific sender has replied to a mail which contains tables that is also copies in the same mail

```
    Sub ImportToExcel()
     Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
     Dim OutlookNameSpace As Namespace
     Dim folder As MAPIfolder
     Dim xDoc As Word.Document
     Dim xTable As Word.Table
     Dim OutlookMail As Variant
     Dim xWb As Workbook
     Dim xWs As Worksheet
     Dim xExcel As Excel.Application
     Dim xRow As Integer
     Dim i As Integer
     Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
     Set OutlookNameSpace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
     Set folder=OutlookNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("DL")
     Set xExcel = New Excel.Application
     Set xWb = xExcel.Workbooks.Add
      xExcel.Visible = True
      Set xWs = xWb.Sheets(1)
       xRow = 1
        For Each OutlookMail In folder.Items
            If OutlookMail.ReceivedTime = "1/12/2019" And OutlookMail.Sender = "Vince Onal" Then
            Set xDoc = OutlookMail.GetInspector.WordEditor
            For i = 1 To xDoc.tables.Count
            Set xTable = xDoc.tables(i)
            xTable.Range.Copy
            xWs.Paste
            xRow = xRow + xTable.Rows.Count + 1
            xWs.Range("A" & CStr(xRow)).Select
                Next
               End If
               Next

                 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To get your format for ReceivedTime:

```
Debug.Print " OutlookObj.ReceivedTime: " & OutlookObj.ReceivedTime
```

You will find there cannot be a match with "1/12/2019"

Try

```
If Format(OutlookMail.ReceivedTime, "mm/dd/yyyy") = "1/12/2019" Then
```